# get the mean var of all columns value and make new column

Tags: python, dataframe

Let say we habe

```
      A , B , C
id    
1     3, 4, 5
2     4 ,5, 2
```

if I want to make a new column D with  ID 1's mean,var  and ID2's mean and var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
df[['avg','var']] = df.agg(['mean','var'], axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C       avg       var
1  3  4  5  4.000000  1.000000
2  4  5  2  3.666667  2.333333
```

Another idea:

```
df = df.assign(avg=df.mean(axis=1),
               var=df.var(axis=1))
print (df)
   A  B  C       avg       var
1  3  4  5  4.000000  1.000000
2  4  5  2  3.666667  2.333333
```

If you want `variance` with `ddof=0` in [`DataFrame.var`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.var.html):

```
df = df.assign(avg=df.mean(axis=1),
               var=df.var(axis=1, ddof=0))
print (df)
   A  B  C       avg       var
1  3  4  5  4.000000  0.666667
2  4  5  2  3.666667  1.555556
```